# Sliding Menu as like as spotify on android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I want to implement sliding menu for my app.
I have done some research for sliding menu and i found [that](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) is useful so I downloaded the library and import it into my project but I did not find any good explanation to use this slide menu with ActionBarSherlock.

Is it possible to implement sliding menu with ActionBarSherlock and also support Android 2.2 and above?

Thank you

Answer (score 7):

> i dont found any good explanation to use this slide menu with SharelockAction bar

I assume that "SharelockAction bar" is ActionBarSherlock. If so:

Step #1: Visit [the project home page](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) that you included as a URL above.

Step #2: Read the ["Setup with ActionBarSherlock" section](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu#setup-with-actionbarsherlock).

If "SharelockAction bar" is referring to something else, please provide a link.

Comment: I saw setup with actionbarsharelock there are 2 way to integrate slidemenu into your project right?... 1st is by "Activity extend SlidingActivity"
2nd is "SlidingMenu view directly in your xml layouts" ..i cant extend my activity by slidingactivity because i am using action bar of actionbarsherlock...I want to integrate by programmatically do u have any sample code to integrate

Comment: Please Share any sample code which uses ActionBarSherlock and SlideMenu library into one project.

Comment: @user1587609: See this fork of the project you cited: https://github.com/iPaulPro/SlidingMenu and the `example-abs/` project in there.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get ActionBarSherlock working with Jeremy Feinsteins library, you just have to extend `SherlockActivity` in all classes instead of Activity. Also replace all `FragmentActivities` with `SherlockFragmentActivity` and so on. Don't forget to set the Theme of the App to: `Theme.Sherlock`

Comment: but If i change it from SlidingMenuActivity to SherlockActivity than setBehindContentView , setBehindOffset , setBehindScrollScale Shows Read Line and Ask me to create New method..

Comment: SlidingMenuActivity is probably a class. There is no SlidingMenuActivity as a default in Android, just change the class from Activity to SherlockActivity

Comment: for sliding menu i have downloaded and added library to my project " com.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenuActivity;" if i change from slidingmenuActivity to SherlockActivity than my setbehindcontentview , setBehindOffset , setBehindscrollScale show that undefined method and red line...

Comment: slidingmenuActivity is not a typ of Activity! Just search for the class slidingmenuActivity in the project and change **that** class